# Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65"

Tags: xcode, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios, xcuitest

I cannot run iOS automation via simulator after update the Xcode version from 14.2 to 15

The app is getting installed in the iPhone Simulator, but seems not able launch the WebDriverAgent

Appium version - 2.5.1
Xcode Version 15.2

```
[WebDriverAgent] xcodebuild exited with code '65' and signal 'null'
```

Log:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 18178FC9-7686-49D1-A9A4-833C1D085672
CrashReporter Key:   B6BCB0BC-C4BF-0812-C839-2525D5F5A721
Hardware Model:      Mac14,10
Process:             WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner [62911]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/57C29643-B0AA-470F-84A5-43D498C73885/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/79558190-7809-4D4F-87BD-735D2E527F8C/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.app/WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner
Identifier:          com.facebook.WebDriverAgentRunner.xctrunner
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [60432]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.57C29643-B0AA-470F-84A5-43D498C73885 [7371]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [4250]

Date/Time:           2024-02-27 21:25:32.7848 +0700
Launch Time:         2024-02-27 21:21:31.1005 +0700
OS Version:          macOS 14.3.1 (23D60)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner [62911]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x18049111c __exceptionPreprocess + 160
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x18008412c objc_exception_throw + 56
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1804a5f78 +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                         0x180495278 ___forwarding___ + 1280
4   CoreFoundation                         0x18049759c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
5   WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103ebb6bc __FBTestmanagerdVersion_block_invoke + 200 (FBXCodeCompatibility.m:127)
6   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
7   libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016e530 _dispatch_once_callout + 28
8   WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103ebb5cc _dispatch_once + 36 (once.h:86) [inlined]
9   WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103ebb5cc FBTestmanagerdVersion + 80 (FBXCodeCompatibility.m:124)
10  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103ea6720 +[FBSessionCommands handleGetStatus:] + 1048 (FBSessionCommands.m:251)
11  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103e462b8 -[FBRoute_TargetAction mountRequest:intoResponse:] + 168 (FBRoute.m:43)
12  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103e32254 __37-[FBWebServer registerRouteHandlers:]_block_invoke + 404 (FBWebServer.m:202)
13  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103e68010 -[RoutingHTTPServer handleRoute:withRequest:response:] + 168 (RoutingHTTPServer.m:199)
14  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103e68b00 __72-[RoutingHTTPServer routeMethod:withPath:parameters:request:connection:]_block_invoke + 64 (RoutingHTTPServer.m:273)
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017ca48 _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke + 112
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18016cd3c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
18  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017bb24 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1272
19  libdispatch.dylib                      0x18017b61c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 40
20  CoreFoundation                         0x1803f1a30 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
21  CoreFoundation                         0x1803ec148 __CFRunLoopRun + 1936
22  CoreFoundation                         0x1803eb5a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
23  Foundation                             0x180dcd68c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 208
24  WebDriverAgentLib                      0x103e310b8 -[FBWebServer startServing] + 324 (FBWebServer.m:80)
25  WebDriverAgentRunner                   0x1025df714 -[UITestingUITests testRunner] + 72 (UITestingUITests.m:44)
26  CoreFoundation                         0x180497750 __invoking___ + 144
27  CoreFoundation                         0x180494ab4 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 276
28  XCTestCore                             0x10368efa0 +[XCTFailableInvocation invokeStandardConventionInvocation:completion:] + 64
29  XCTestCore                             0x10368ef58 __90+[XCTFailableInvocation invokeInvocation:withTestMethodConvention:lastObservedErrorIssue:]_block_invoke_3 + 24
30  XCTestCore                             0x10368e7d8 __81+[XCTFailableInvocation invokeWithAsynchronousWait:lastObservedErrorIssue:block:]_block_invoke + 300
31  XCTestCore                             0x103651928 +[XCTSwiftErrorObservation observeErrorsInBlock:] + 256
32  XCTestCore                             0x10368e5b8 +[XCTFailableInvocation invokeWithAsynchronousWait:lastObservedErrorIssue:block:] + 184
33  XCTestCore                             0x10368eca8 +[XCTFailableInvocation invokeInvocation:withTestMethodConvention:lastObservedErrorIssue:] + 432
34  XCTestCore                             0x10368f02c +[XCTFailableInvocation invokeInvocation:lastObservedErrorIssue:] + 68
35  XCTestCore                             0x103682cbc __24-[XCTestCase invokeTest]_block_invoke.78 + 96
36  XCTestCore                             0x103648ad4 -[XCTestCase(XCTIssueHandling) _caughtUnhandledDeveloperExceptionPermittingControlFlowInterruptions:caughtInterruptionException:whileExecutingBlock:] + 160
37  XCTestCore                             0x103682888 -[XCTestCase invokeTest] + 668
38  XCTestCore                             0x1036840d0 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.116 + 32
39  XCTestCore                             0x103648ad4 -[XCTestCase(XCTIssueHandling) _caughtUnhandledDeveloperExceptionPermittingControlFlowInterruptions:caughtInterruptionException:whileExecutingBlock:] + 160
40  XCTestCore                             0x103683b94 __26-[XCTestCase performTest:]_block_invoke.106 + 492
41  XCTestCore                             0x103667244 +[XCTContext _runInChildOfContext:forTestCase:markAsReportingBase:block:] + 172
42  XCTestCore                             0x103667144 +[XCTContext
```

I've tried updated the appium to the latest version and build WebDriverAgent in the Xcode.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE3wM.png)